# Ffmpeg command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg commands in my nodejs application. I dont want to using any npm packages like fluent-ffmpeg.
Till now I have done this :

```
var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i',fileName+'.wav' ,fileName+'.amr','-acodec libopencore_amrnb', '-ab 12200k', '-ac 1', '-ar 8000']);
            // input_file.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);
            // ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(output_stream);

            ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log(data.toString());
            });

            ffmpeg.stderr.on('end', function () {
                console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
            });

            ffmpeg.stderr.on('exit', function () {
                console.log('child process exited');
            });

            ffmpeg.stderr.on('close', function() {
                console.log('...closing time! bye');
            });
```

In output it gives error like this :

```
Unrecognized option 'acodec libopencore_amrnb'
```

I have installed all binaries required. Just need to know what command i have to pass in `spawn()` like :

```
var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i',fileName+'.wav' ,fileName+'.amr','-acodec libopencore_amrnb', '-ab 12200k', '-ac 1', '-ar 8000']);
```

I have tried the command on terminal and works perfectly. All i want is the correct way to pass command (options) in `spawn()`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `spawn`, you pass the command, and then an array where every flag *and every associated argument* is a separate element.

So instead of `'-acodec libopencore_amrnb'`, like you have, you want `'-acodec', 'libopencore_amrnb'`. They need to be two separate elements.

Comment: Did you keep the `-` prefix? Try this, this works: `spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', fileName + '.wav', '-acodec', 'libopencore_amrnb', '-ac', '1', '-ar', '8k', 'output.amr'])`